# Выравнивание текста на фото по x. Питон

Tags: python, изображения, pillow

Помогите пожалуйста сделать выравнивание текста по x в питон.

```py
text = "Тест"
image = Image.open("Prevpng.png")
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 100)
drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
drawer.text((340, 460), text, font=font, fill='#FAACAC')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Выравнивание текста по X в Pillow осуществляется изменением аргумента функции `ImageDraw.text`

( [документация](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text) )

Пример отступа от края на 100 пикселей:

```py
...
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((100, 0),"Sample Text",(255,255,255),font=font)
```

Чтобы выравнять текст по центру можно использовать метод [`ImageDraw.textsize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.textsize), который вернёт размер текста в пикселях. Отцентровать текст можно математическим методом, зная [размер изображения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444548/how-do-i-get-the-picture-size-with-pil) и размер текста. (Центральный пиксель текста должен находится на половине размера изображения)